# How do I create a project without the project folder?

Tags: python, pyramid, paster

I'm new to pyramid and paster, just reading the docs for now. I use virtualenv and inside the virtualenv dir I want to start a pyramid project. The problem is that I would like for paster to not create a dir with the project name, and instead put all the scaffold files on the current dir (the venv root).

I thought about just not using paster but I still wouldn't know how to point to my app on development.ini "use" option.

I could also have my virtualenv on an entirely different place of my filesystem, but that seems weird to me (maybe virtualenvwrapper could make it easier). Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just bike shedding because how you create the project and the virtualenv are irrelevant and you can place either of them anywhere, including within each other.

However, if you really want to, you can `paster create -t pyramid_starter -o .. <current_directory_name>` to create the project within the current directory.

To create a new project:

```
cd ~/work/my_repo
virtualenv --no-site-packages env
env/bin/pip install pyramid
env/bin/paster create -t pyramid_starter -o .. my_repo
git init
echo 'env' > .gitignore
git add .
```

I'll usually do this when setting up a new machine:

```
cd ~/work
git clone /path/to/<my repo>.git
cd my_repo
virtualenv --no-site-packages env
env/bin/pip install -e . # equivalent to env/bin/python setup.py develop
```

Using the setup I just mentioned, you'd want to add the `env` directory to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 3):

It is confusing at first but your code really doesn't need to be in your virtual environment directory at all. Actually it's better not to put your code inside your environment, as you might want to use different environments with the same code, for example to test your code with different versions of Python or different versions of a library.

virtualenvwrapper does put all your environments in a single place. virtualenvwrapper is a convenient tool on top of virtualenv but you don't need it to put your code and your environments in different places. Maybe you should get a bit more comfortable with virtualenv itself before starting to use virtualenvwrapper.

You should let paster create a directory with the project name. This is the directory that you will commit in version control (eg. git, mercurial...). You don't want to commit the directory containing the virtual environment.